# Change shell error

Tags: command-line, bash

Ubuntu 20.04

I am trying to change the shell for a user-backuppc:

```
brad@ubuntu:~$ su - backuppc /usr/bin/bash
Password: 
/usr/bin/bash: 1: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
brad@ubuntu:~$ whereis bash
bash: /usr/bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

Update: This was solved

> -, -l, --login
> Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
>
> ```
>              o      clears all the environment variables except TERM and variables specified by --whitelist-environment
>
>              o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
>
>              o      changes to the target user's home directory
>
>              o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell
> ```

butt:

```
brad@zika:~$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

What I am doing wrong here? Thanks folks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Did you mean to run `sudo -u backuppc chsh` or maybe `su backuppc chsh`? Are the first and second parts of your question related to each other? Please [edit] your question and give us some context. The `Authentication failure` is what you get when you give a wrong password. If that is not what is happening, we need more information.

Comment: no, is not wrong password, sudo works fine but su does not work

Comment: Please explain what you are doing. `su -` requires the password of the `root` user, while `sudo` will require the password of the `brad` user.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, the root account is not activated. As a consequence, the command `su -` will not work. This command starts a login shell for the root user, which does not work. `su - backuppc` starts a login shell for user `backuppc`. This works if that user exists on the system.

To open an interactive prompt with root privileges, use `sudo -i` . Yet, for many administrator tasks, there is rarely a need to keep a terminal with root privileges open. Instead precede the commands that require root privileges with `sudo`.

To change the login shell of another user, for example user `backuppc`, you can use

```
sudo chsh backuppc -s <path-to-shell>
```

Comment: su - backuppc -s /bin/bash worked too. Activated or enabled? root on my box is enabled.

Comment: Semantics: please enlighten me on the correct term and I will update it. On a default Ubuntu install, root account is disabled. su - therefore does not work. However, su - backuppc will. I will add a little note on that.

Comment: "disabled" is not politically correct maybe that is why you initially used the "activated" term :) :) :)